# Can I update the Messenger bot which is already approved by Facebook?

Tags: bots, messenger, facebook-messenger

I have created Messenger bot which is approved and available for public. Now I want to add other use cases and also change the text messages which are being sent from the bot. One of the use cases is the choose language feature. So if I change the bot use cases is there a probobality that some day Facebook will block the bot due to my made changes. So if yes, then how can I prevent that?

Comment: Please hit that "edit" button and edit your question to make it clearer. What exactly does your "messenger bot" do, what does it have to do with Facebook and what exactly are you asking?

Comment: Messenger Bot is https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform, My question was not related to the problems with my implementation of the bot, that is why I'm not describing what does my bot. The bot is implemented and successfully approved by the Facebook. My question is the following: Can I make changes in my bot and Facebook will not block it? because it is a new release of the bot and usually when you give new releases in any platform the authority of the platform should review your new release and decide whether to approve or not.

Comment: I've only published apps on FB for personal use, not public, but my experience has been that they will only re-review it if the updated version requires new permissions. That said, the fact that you're even asking implies that you're trying to do something shady.

Comment: @ I wrestled a bear once. `That said, the fact that you're even asking implies that you're trying to do something shady`: cobblers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once your bot is approved by Facebook you can do whatever you want with it.

We published a bot months ago and update its answers and its behavior in a daily basis without waiting for Facebook to re-approve the bot (*thank god because the approval was so long*).

But keep in mind that if your bot is reported as spam by a *certain amount* of people, Facebook can automatically disable your bot (and/or the associated Facebook App) and you'll need to fix your bot and explain why it was reported as spam (if you can).

Comment: Thanks! Yea, actually the review proccess takes very long.